# Convert back from ILS currency to a number

Tags: reactjs, type-conversion, currency, implicit-conversion, data-conversion

I have a Currency input that is formatted to ILS (israeli new Shekel) and I want my onChange event to record the value, but as a number. this is what I tried:

```
                   <CurrencyInput
                    onChange={(e) =>
                      setAmount(Number(e.target.value.replace("&#8362", "")))
                    }
                    decimalsLimit={2}
                    intlConfig={{ locale: "he-IS", currency: "ILS" }}
                  ></CurrencyInput>
```

However, I still get a NaN (not a number) result.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are using the react-currency-input-field npm package, judging from the component name and props passed.
The package makes room for a prop called `onValueChange` which takes in a function. The first argument of that function is the string value of the number inputed. You can convert that into a number conveniently, and your code can be changed as so:

```
<CurrencyInput
  onValueChange={(value) => {
    (e) => setAmount(Number(value))
  }}
  decimalsLimit={2}
  intlConfig={{ locale: "he-IS", currency: "ILS" }}
/>
```

`CurrencyInput` is a self closing component by the way.

You can also get the `values` object (with more info), as the third argument in the `onValueChange` function.

```
  onValueChange={(value, _, values) => {
    (e) => setAmount(Number(values.value))
  }}
```

The object looks something like this:

```
{ 
  float: 1234, 
  formatted: "‏1,234 ‏₪",
  value: "1234" 
}
```

Hope this was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

A friend helped me out, the solution is:

```
Number(e.target.value.replace(/\D/g,''))
```